# How to access Flask test server from the outside of local network?

Tags: python, rest, flask, python-requests, webserver

I am doing experiments with requests trough proxy for web-scraping project.
In order to test requests headers and content i've build a simple flask server like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    ret_str = f'<- {request} ->\n' \
              f'<----- HEADERS ----->\n' \
              f'{request.headers}\n' \
              f'<----- DATA ----->\n' \
              f'{request.data}\n'
    print(ret_str)
    return ret_str

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Which is run perfectly fine if access through localhost by **127.0.0.1:5000** (with `app.run()`) and through local network by requesting the local address **10.214.14.222:5000** (which is displayed by **ipconfig**).

But if i try to access it through my 4G connection or through proxy, request fails. According to https://ipchecker.io/, my outside ip is, let's say **216.94.151.186**, but requesting my page using **216.94.151.186:5000** gives 'page not found'.

How to access the test server from outside the local network? Can anyone please help?

**SOLUTION:** Set up port forwarding on router and make computer that run flask server IP-address static on router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need to do is make your specified port available on your router. This is done with port forwarding. The location of this tab can switch depending on your router provider but once this is done you can just visit [This link](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) which shows your public IP. Then you can just visit: 000.00.000.00:5000 <-- Replace zero's with public IP.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it at home, since I don't think it is a good idea to mess with an office router settings. Will report if it helped or not later.

Comment: Hope it will work for you. Curious if it works out for you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the advice mate. This should work, but as I've found out there is also some problem in the my ISP site. But thank you for the advice anyway!

Comment: You solution has worked perfectly, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that port 5000 is opened in your router.

If you have access to linux, you can use **nmap** to check which ports are open or go to https://portchecker.co/ and check to see if port 5000 is open.

Comment: Thanks mate, as I found, port 5000 is closed. But since it is a company network, can't change settings. But I will try it at home tonight. Thanks <3

Comment: hay mate! Did as you adviced, didn't help much, but after I've did some reading the advice is correct. However the problem is with my ISP. Will try to speak with them later tonight.